# LinkageError on an OSGI system package

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

I'm getting this exception when trying to run a bundle activator:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving
method "com.openaf.osgi.OSGIUtils$.mapToDictionary(Lscala/collection/immutable/Map;)Ljava/util/Dictionary;"
the class loader (instance of
org/apache/felix/framework/BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoaderJava5) of
the current class, com/openaf/test/TestBundleActivator, and the class
loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for resolved
class, com/openaf/osgi/OSGIUtils$, have different Class objects for
the type a/util/Dictionary; used in the signature
    at com.openaf.test.TestBundleActivator.start(TestBundleActivator.scala:11)
```

It looks like the `java.util.Dictionary` has been loaded by two different classloaders but I don't know why. The class that is causing the problem (`com.openaf.osgi.OSGIUtils`) is a system package. i.e.

```
hm.put("org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra", "sun.misc, com.openaf.osgi")
```

This is the manifest of the bundle that `TestBundleActivator` lives in:

```
Manifest-Version: 1
Bnd-LastModified: 1345098244802
Bundle-Activator: com.openaf.test.TestBundleActivator
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: test.impl
Bundle-SymbolicName: test.impl
Bundle-Version: 0
Created-By: 1.7.0_04 (Oracle Corporation)
Export-Package: com.openaf.test;uses:="scala.collection,scala.collection
 .immutable,com.openaf.test.api,scala.collection.mutable,scala.reflect,o
 rg.osgi.framework,com.openaf.osgi,scala.runtime,scala,com.openaf.utils"
 ;version="0.0.0"
Import-Package: com.openaf.osgi,com.openaf.test.api,com.openaf.utils,org
 .osgi.framework,scala,scala.collection,scala.collection.immutable,scala
 .collection.mutable,scala.reflect,scala.runtime
Tool: Bnd-1.44.0
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? I just presumed because it is in the system packages that it should be loaded by the base classloader. It appears this isn't the case.

Thanks, Nick.

EDIT - 
I should say what I'm trying to do. I have a package on the classpath when the felix application is launched and I would like it to be available to all bundles. I thought the `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra` property was the way to do it. Is that correct?

Comment: Is this upon first time activation, or after stopping and restarting? After an update? Also, I think you should resolve the system packages and package the com.openaf.osgi package 'properly'. It may well be the cause of this issue. Also, the error message says 'a.util.Dictionary', not 'java.util.Dictionary' but assume that's a copy/paste error?

Comment: It is on first activation (no cache) or after stopping and restarting (I've not tried after an update). I get the same exception each time. This is not a copy and paste mistake, that is the exact exception that I get. I'm happy to package things properly, please elaborate. What I actually want is for that package to be available to every bundle. I thought the best way to do that was add it to the system package, I could be wrong though, please let me know.

Comment: Ok, well if there is a package called a.util you need to find out why there are two exports of it. They must be in your bundles or third party bundles you added... Use the Gogo (http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-gogo.html) 'which' command to list where classes are loaded, e.g. "which [bundle id] a.util.Dictionary" inserting your bundle id (you can find this using 'lb')

Comment: Regarding the packaging, there's no need to add that package to system packages. Simply put it into a bundle and export the package, then import the package for all bundles that need to use it. This is kinda the point of modularised programming!

Comment: It's a weird one alright. There isn't anything that exports a.util. That's my error message but maybe it is being garbled in someway. Initially I had the package as a separate bundle and it worked fine. I will go back to that. It's a shame as I know that every bundle needs it but I guess I will just have to import it into every bundle. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If that works, I suggest you answer your own question.